# Append a list to the first row and column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a 4300 x 4300 pandas dataframe (rows and columns) and want to add a list to the first rows and the first column. I don't know how to do so, without filling the dataframe completely with zeros…

Example for old 4300 x 4300 dataframe (excerpt):

[image]

Example of list to add:
["axis","output","group","plurality","record"]

Example for new A x A dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Can you add some sample data with 5x5 df and expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values in list not exist in index and columns use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`Index.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.append.html) or [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html):

```
L = ["axis","output","group","plurality","record"]
#if order is important
df = df.reindex(index=df.index.append(pd.Index(L)), columns= df.columns.append(pd.Index(L)))

#if index, columns values should be sorted
df = df.reindex(index=df.index.union(L), columns= df.columns.union(L))
```

If possible values exist in index, columns and order is important:

```
L1 = [x for x in L if x not in df.index]
L2 = [x for x in L if x not in df.columns]

df = df.reindex(index=df.index.append(pd.Index(L1)), columns= df.columns.append(pd.Index(L2)))
```